# Number of subgroups of a direct product group of prime order.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is

If $G$ is the group obtained by the direct product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where p is a prime number. Find the number of subgroups of $G$ with order $p$.

I have been thinking about it and the problem appears simple to me. It appears too good to be true therefore I would appreciate if someone can check my process.

The order of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ will be $p^n$. But there will be $n$ subgroups of the form

$H_{i}$ $=$ {$(e_{1},....e_{i-1},a_{i},e_{i+1},....,e_{n}) : a_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$}

In other words $H_{i}$ consist of $n$-tuples where in the $i$th component any element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i}$ can occur and where every other element is an identity element. All the subgroups if this form will have order $p$. There will be $n$ such subgroups. I cant think of any other subgroup with order $p$ since $p$ is prime. But this looks to easy to be true. I would appreciate if someone can comment on my procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Every element of $\Bbb Z_p$ except $0$ has order $p$; why?

- Let $a=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ be any non-identity element of $G$; what is the order of $a$? What is the order of the subgroup generated by $a$?
- How many elements of $G$ generate a subgroup of order $p$?
- How many different generators does a group of order $p$ have?

Once you've answered those questions you have all of the information needed to answer the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Here is my answers for the three bullet points. 1) The order of $a$ is $p^n$. The order of subgroup generated by $a$ is $p^n$. (2) $n(p-1)$ elements of G generate a subgroup of order $p$ since there are $n$ spots and $p-1$ non identity elements to fill those spots. (3)A group of order $p$ has $p-1$ different generators. Thus I have again arrived at answer ${n(p-1)}/(p-1)$ = $n$. I still suspect I missed something.

Comment: @Jacob: No, the order of $a$ is just $p$: each $a_k$ satisfies $$\underbrace{a_k+\ldots+a_k}_{n\text{ copies}}=0\;,$$ and at least one $a_k$ is non-zero. *Every* non-identity element of $G$ has order $p$; this of course affects the answer to the second point. Your answer to the third point is right, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The answer for (2) will be $p^n-1$. That is all elements except for identity. Hence the final answer would be ${p^n-1}/(p-1)$

Comment: @Jacob: (Sorry to have run out on you; I got called away.)  Yes, that's right. You're welcome.